# Grouping rows by proximity of floats in a python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, cluster-analysis

It feels so straight forward but I haven't found the answer to my question yet. How does one group by proximity, or closeness, of two floats in pandas?

Ok, I could do this the loopy way but my data is big and I hope I can expand my pandas skills with your help and do this elegantly:

I have a column of times in nanoseconds in my DataFrame. I want to group these based on the proximity of their values to little clusters. Most of them will be two rows per cluster maybe up to five or six. I do not know the number of clusters. It will be a massive amount of very small clusters.
I thought I could e.g. introduce a second index or just an additional column with 1 for all rows of the first cluster, 2 for the second and so forth so that groupby gets straight forward thereafter.
something like:

|  | t (ns) | cluster |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 71 | 1524957248.4375 | 1 |
| 72 | 1524957265.625 | 1 |
| 699 | 14624846476.5625 | 2 |
| 700 | 14624846653.125 | 2 |
| 701 | 14624846661.287 | 2 |
| 1161 | 25172864926.5625 | 3 |
| 1160 | 25172864935.9375 | 3 |

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to create the "cluster" column from the index based on the proximity of the successive values, you could use:

```
thresh = 1
df['cluster'] = df.index.to_series().diff().gt(thresh).cumsum().add(1)
```

using the "t (ns)":

```
thresh = 1
df['cluster'] = df['t (ns)'].diff().gt(thresh).cumsum().add(1)
```

output:

```
            t (ns)  cluster
71    1.524957e+09        1
72    1.524957e+09        1
699   1.462485e+10        2
700   1.462485e+10        2
701   1.462485e+10        2
1161  2.517286e+10        3
1160  2.517286e+10        3
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! Your suggestion used the index which is a bit dangerous in my case, I should have added but  df['t (ns)'].diff().gt(thresh).cumsum().add(1) seems to do the job neat and fast, thank you!

Comment: @Alice of course, use whatever makes most sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can 'round' the `t (ns)` column by floor dividing them with a threshold value and looking at their differences:

```py
df[['t (ns)']].assign(
    cluster=(df['t (ns)'] // 10E7)
    .diff().gt(0).cumsum().add(1)
)
```

Or you can experiment with the number of clusters you try to organize your data:

```py
bins=3
df[['t (ns)']].assign(
    bins=pd.cut(
        df['t (ns)'], bins=bins).cat.rename_categories(range(1, bins + 1)
    )
)
```